# tengo un problema con mostrar diferentes paginas en una LCD en arduino con hilos

Tags: hilos, bucles, arduino

Este es parte del código donde intento mostrar pantallas con valores de sensores, pero solo muestra la primera pantalla y no cambia, mientras que los hilos de sensores siguen funcionando bien

```
void Control_Pantalla(struct pt *pt){

  PT_BEGIN(pt);

  static long tiempoPantalla=0;

  while(true){

    for (int i =1; i < 4; i++){
      Pantalla.firstPage();   
      do 
      {  
      draw(i); 
      } 
      while( Pantalla.nextPage() ); 
      tiempoPantalla=millis(); 
      PT_WAIT_UNTIL(pt,(millis()-tiempoPantalla)>1000); 
    }

  }
  PT_END(pt);

}

void loop() {     

    Control_Pantalla(&hiloPantalla);
    Control_Sensores(&hiloSensores);
    Control_Bomba(&hiloBomba);


}
```